# Microsoft Interop - Outlook V15 vs Microsoft 365 Outlook Pre-Release

Tags: outlook, office-interop

I'm getting the exception 80080005 from Com+, if I use the last stable lib [15.0.4797.1004] with the Outlook pre-release version on [with the switch_button called "Try the new Outlook" in the upper-right corner of the application].
So currently I've suggested to collegues, to keep the pre-release off, waiting for a new Interop Update.

Anyone with the same issue?

I hope in an update of INTEROP Libe, also an unstable version, that will manage the new Outlook 365 pre-release mode.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`. This is by design – COM system refuses to marshal COM calls between processes running in different security contexts. Make sure that neither or both processes are running with elevated (Run As Administrator) privileges.